# How to duplicate Google doc keeping original date?

Tags: google-drive

I had coworker create bunch of Google documents under his account. He shared documents with me and company, but after few months he left. He didn't transfer ownership to either me or company. Now I have to find a way to remove him as owner/editor/viewer. Only way I see is to copy all documents under company account.

Is there a way that I can copy/create new document which should be identical in everything with original (content, creation date...) except owners and editors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Google Drive there is no way to make a copy of file and keep the creation date the same as the original file.

Regarding a reference, I'm sorry, I haven't one. Google very rarely mentions non-included / missing features.